# onClickListener in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, button, listener, preference

I have this onClickListener in onCreate method of my PreferenceActivity, but it gives me error.

Here is the PrefereceActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
             // do something.
            } 
        });
}
```

it gives me this error:

```
unable to start activity componentinfo java.lang.nullpointerexception
```

any idea what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: My SettingsPreference opens Dialog that holds that "button2".

Comment: The `Button` is very likely `null`.

Comment: First of all, you're not using dialog.xml anywhere. Secondly, you're not setting a content view / layout. You're adding preferences from a resource. Like I said, the error occurs with the Button. You shouldn't need to use Buttons in a PreferenceActivity anyway.

Comment: My SettingsPreference opens Dialog that holds that "button2".

Comment: Read the link in my answer below. There's a perfectly good example including examples with dialogs. What you're doing now is wrong.

Comment: Edit your question and show us your `settings.xml` file, please. If you have a null pointer exception thats because you do not have any `button2` declared at this xml file, simple as that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Button` is causing your `NullPointerException` because you haven't set a layout and therefore it is `null`. You shouldn't need to use buttons in a `PreferenceActivity` anyway.

There's a perfectly good example of using PreferenceActivity over at the Android developer site: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html